# Keras - shouldn't two class variables result in four possible outputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, binary, keras, classification

I've been using Keras for a heart classification problem. Most guides online usually train a binary classification problem by signifying 0 and 1 as different states. In my case, I followed this by assigning inputs related to the onset of ventricular tachycardia as '1', and normal sinus rhythm inputs as '0'.  I've followed this and successfully gotten good results, but I am now looking to print a confusion matrix and have gotten quite... confused.

Keras gives me weights at the output layer between 0 and 1, which is expected. A prediction is made based on that. However, shouldn't I have four possible outputs? I should have ventricular tachycardia, NOT ventricular tachycardia, normal sinus rhythm, and NOT normal sinus rhythm (just like in a confusion matrix). Currently, I get an output which is either one or the other, and there is no "absence" of a prediction to check. I am unsure whether I have a problem with my understanding, or I can simply modify my Keras code to facilitate this.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `predict_classes()` method on your model. That way you would get the classes. FYI, those numbers you get with `predict()` method are probabilities of your positive class (i.e. ventricular tachycardia). So everything above 0.5 is regarded as belonging to positive class and everything below 0.5 is regarded as belonging to negative class (i.e. normal sinus rhythm).

Comment: After reading your question for the second time, I suspect that I may have understood it wrongly: basically for each of the inputs you want to answer two questions: 1. Is it "ventricular tachycardia" or not? and 2. Is it "normal sinus rhythm" or not? And these questions are independent of one another, right? Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like. Moreso, I think I am not understanding why we need to give Keras data on what a normal sinus rhythm (class variable 0) is. Couldn't we just solely give it ventricular tachycardia data, and if it is uncertain it will conclude it is "not" ventricular tachycardia? Because right now, the absence of ventricular tachycardia = normal sinus rhythm, which is technically incorrect as there are many other heart states that exist.

Comment: Then, you need to have training data consists of all the four states: normal/not-normal sinus rhythm and ventricular tachycardia and no ventricular tachycardia. If you only give it the data related to the positive classes then your model cannot infer what negative classes look like and therefore the accuracy of the model would not be high. Further, in this case you should have Dense layer with two units as the last layer and the loss of it should be `binaray_crossentropy` since one sample may have both or none the mentioned states as well, if I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: OK thanks, this is a lot more clear now. I simply need a lot of data from all sorts of sources (covering not ventricular tachycardia means a huge amount of data...). Any recommendations for managing the imbalanced data sizes that would naturally occur with this approach? Wouldn't recall scores be biased?

Comment: One way of dealing with that is using cost-sensitive learning. Basically, you penalize misclassifcations of minority class more heavily in order to force the learning algorithm to consider the minority class as well. I think [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/d43d6fa19d2) and [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/) and [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/13490/28035) on data science stackexchange might help you in this case.

Comment: The thing you described in your question is called one-vs-rest classification.